# different results of crypt.crypt on ubuntu vs fedora

Tags: python, ubuntu, fedora

I want to hash a password with the [crypt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) module using *blowfish* encryption.

On Fedora 29 I get the correct result:

```sh
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan  3 2019, 09:14:01) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)] on linux

>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("password", "$2y$08$heregoesasaltstring...")
'$2y$08$heregoesasaltstring...ZR2mMC1niL.pkti1MfmoP.3XVbdoNHm'
>>>
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 it returns nothing:

```sh
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 25 2018, 03:50:46) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux

>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("password", "$2y$08$heregoesasaltstring...")
>>>
```

Python 3.7.1 on Fedora comes from the default repos, while on Ubuntu the problem can be seen with both the python 3.7.1 from the official repos and the one I found on an [external PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Is there any environment variable or underlying program/library that could change the behavior of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Your salt string is invalid on Ubuntu. Try dropping all those dollar signs.

---

From the Python documentation of `crypt` module you linked:

> This module implements an interface to the *crypt(3)* routine

> *salt* (either a random 2 or 16 character string, possibly prefixed with `$digit$` to indicate the method) which will be used to perturb the encryption algorithm. The characters in salt must be in the set `[./a-zA-Z0-9]`, with the exception of Modular Crypt Format which prefixes a `$digit$`.

From `man 3 crypt`:

> ERRORS
>
> EINVAL: salt has the wrong format.

I wrote a test program to confirm this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *s = crypt("password", "$2y$08$heregoesasaltstring...");
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", errno == EINVAL, errno == ENOSYS, errno == EPERM);
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output on Ubuntu 18.04 is

```
ibug@ubuntu:~/t $ gcc t.c -lcrypt
ibug@ubuntu:~/t $ a.out
1
0
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
139|ibug@ubuntu:~/t $
```

I don't have Fedora in hand, so I didn't test it. You can copy the test program and compile & run it yourself.